# Is it possible to hide certain tabs from a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am wanting to implement a `UITabBarController` environment (several view controller chains managed by their own `UINavigationControllers`), but don't want all the tabs to be visible in the `TabBar` (I only want 3 of the 10 tabs visible).  The "Home" screen will have buttons that I will use to switch to that specific "tab".  Is this possible?  If not, can someone suggest an alternative method for accomplishing this behavior?

I have looked through the `UITabBarController` class reference and saw nothing to indicate a method like "`willDisplayTab`" or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UITabBarController *controller = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

controller.viewControllers = [NSArray arraywithObjects:v1,v2,v3,nil];
```

this will return you the array of viewcontorllers (tabs).When you want to remove or add additional new tabs you could change the array of viewContrllers.

Yoo can for example keep all viewcontrollers in an array and the visible ones in another.

But the question is when will you update the visible tabs?

Comment: Well, I want the same 3 tabs always visible and the other tabs always hidden.  I only want to switch to those tabs programmatically and have the TabBar stay static.

Comment: i assume you will access your hiden tabs from home so just add the hiden viewcontrolelr to array when you tap the corresponding button.In the viewwilldisappear method of the hidden ones you set your array back to visible viewcontrollers

Comment: you also need to change the corresponding tabbar items

Comment: But I also want to keep the current navigation index for each path of VC's.

Comment: Via code only.  Not ever visible in the TabBar.  That is my dilemma, I think I can implement this all manually, but I was hoping to subclass UITabBarController and make it work.